# Delete an image after it is uploaded to app and previewed

Tags: reactjs

I am looking to delete an image after I have uploaded it and sent it to a preview.

I have tried delete requests however they are not currently working.

```
class OfferMedia extends Component {
    state = {
       files: [],
       imagesPreviewUrls: []
 };
    _handleImageChange = e =>{
       e.preventDefault();

      // FileList to Array
       let files = Array.from(e.target.files);

      // File Reader for Each file and and update state arrays
        files.forEach((file, i) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onloadend = () => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              files: [...prevState.files, file],
               imagesPreviewUrls: [...prevState.imagesPreviewUrls, 
               reader.result]
          }));
       }

       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     });
  }

      render() {
       let {imagesPreviewUrls} = this.state;
       return (

         <div className="animated">
             <Card>
                <CardHeader>
                  <h5>Image Upload</h5>
                 </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>

         <div>
          <Input className="upload" type="file" onChange={this._handleImageChange} multiple/>
            {imagesPreviewUrls.map(function(imagePreviewUrl, i){
                return <img key={i} src={imagePreviewUrl} />
            })}
  </div>
        </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </div>
    );
   }
  }

   export default OfferMedia;
```

I ultimately would like to have a delete button on the corner of the image (or a seperate one beneath the image), so that when the user clicks on the button, it will delete the image from both the DOM and the backend.

Comment: You mean delete from the server?

Comment: from both the server and the front-end. as in, you can see the preview of the image, but when you hit delete, i'd like for that preview to not be deleted